# How to add particles sks file as overlay on background image using Sprite Kit in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, sprite-kit

I have looked everywhere on how to do this but this is as close I can get. I have set a background image programmatically in MyScene.m file and also within the same file a particle emitter sks file. But the effects doesn't appear although the text in bottom right corner is appearing (counting nodes and fps). So one would think the effect would also appear but it does not. Any ideas how to fix this?

MyScene.m

```
-(void) didMoveToView:(SKView *)view {
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"MyParticle" ofType:@"sks"];
    SKEmitterNode *node = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:path];

    node.particlePosition = CGPointMake(550, 500);
    node.particleBirthRate = 10;

    [self addChild:node];

    SKTexture *backgroundTexture = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"Scene22"];
    SKSpriteNode *background = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:backgroundTexture size:self.view.frame.size];
    background.position = (CGPoint) {CGRectGetMidX(self.view.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.view.frame)};

    [self addChild:background];
}
```

The view controller has the view did load method, also tried viewWillLoadWithSubviews but didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

You've added the particle effect first, and then the sprite. This will make the particle effect draw first, then the background sprite is drawn over the particle effect.

You can either reverse the order in which you run `addChild:` or simply use the `zPosition` property to bring the particle effect in front of the background sprite.

Comment: I have a problem with the my backgroundTexture it doesn't display the image in full screen. The height is full screen but it is compressed from the right so it´s like 1/4 of screen from the right is blank. I´m using viewWillLayoutSubviews in my view controller and configuring the scene like this                                SFMyScene *scene = [SFMyScene sceneWithSize:skView.bounds.size];
scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;

Answer (score 0):

actually it would be:

```
node.particleZPosition = 10; //not zPostion for emitters
```

and

```
background.zPosition = 0; //some values to this effect
```

Laters...